# asp.net MVC TinyMCE disable URL when selecting value from Link List

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

I'm using tinyMCE as a html editor inside my website.
When inserting a link I can select a link from 'Link List'.
I want a behavior that when I select an item from this list the URL becomes disabled. & on the other hand: when selecting 'None' I want to enable the link again.
[image: Link list disable URL]

Does anybody can give me an idea on how I should do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can do this by manipulating the plugin's code so that it does just that what you want :) Find a very short explanation here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin